# Cambiar el formato de chat interno

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un chat interno en una aplicación, lo cual para mostrar todos los mensajes, se abre un modal.

Y para mostrar esos mensajes uso `jquery`, para darles formato con una plantilla de bootstrap.

Adjunto el [Link](https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/components/direct-chat.html) del ejemplo.

```
$.each(data.seguimientos, function (i, o) {

                    card += "<br>";
                    if (o.Contacto != null) {
                        card += "<div class='direct-chat-msg'>";
                        card += "<div class='direct-chat-infos clearfix'>";
                        card += "<span class='direct-chat-name float-left'>"

                        if (o.AgenteId != 0) {
                            card += o.Agente.Nombre;
                        }
                        else {
                            card += o.Contacto.Nombre;
                        }
                        card += "</span>";
                        card += "<span class='direct-chat-timestamp float-right'>" + moment(o.Fecha).format(format1) + "</span>";
                        card += "</div>";
                        if (o.Mensaje == null) {
                            card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'></div>";
                        }
                        else {
                            card += "<img class='direct-chat-img' src='@Url.Content("Content/Images/user-solid.svg")' alt='message user image'>";
                            card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'>" + o.Mensaje.replaceAll("\n", "<br>")
                            if (o.Mensaje != null && o.Archivos != null && o.Archivos != "undefined") {

                                //card += "<br>" + o.Archivos; + "<br>"
                                card += "<br>";
                                //card += "<div class='row'>";
                                var nameFiles = new Array();
                                nameFiles = o.Archivos.split(',');
                                console.log('namesFiles: ' + nameFiles);

                                for (let i = 0; i < nameFiles.length; i++) {
                                    console.log('nameFiles[i]: ' + nameFiles[i]);

                                    var name = o.SolicitudId + "-" + nameFiles[i];
                                    var path = "/Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name;

                                    card += "<div>";
                                    if (nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") || nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif")) {
                                        card += "<a data-gallery='manual2' href='" + path + "' target='_blank'>";
                                        card += "<img src='" + path + "' style='width:200px;height:200px;text-align:center; border-radius: 5px;' >";
                                        card += "</a>";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        card += "<a href='./../../Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name + "' target='_blank'>" + name + "</a>";
                                    }
                                    card += "</div>";

                                    //card += "<a href='./../../Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name + "' target='_blank'>" + name + "</a>";
                                }
                            }
                            + "</div>";
                        }

                        card += "</div>";
                    }
                    else {
                        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        card += "<div class='direct-chat-msg right'>";
                        card += "<div class='direct-chat-infos clearfix'>";
                        card += "<span class='direct-chat-name float-right'>"

                        if (o.AgenteId != 0) {
                            card += o.Agente.Nombre;
                        }
                        else {
                            card += o.Contacto.Nombre;
                        }
                        card += "</span>";
                        card += "<span class='direct-chat-timestamp float-left'>" + moment(o.Fecha).format(format1) + "</span>";
                        card += "</div>";
                        if (o.Mensaje == null) {
                            card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'></div>";
                        }
                        else {
                            card += "<img class='direct-chat-img' src='@Url.Content("Content/Images/user-solid.svg")' alt='message user image'>";
                            card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'>" + o.Mensaje.replaceAll("\n", "<br>")
                            if (o.Mensaje != null && o.Archivos != null && o.Archivos != "undefined") {

                                //card += "<br>" + o.Archivos; + "<br>"
                                card += "<br>";
                                //card += "<div class='row'>";
                                var nameFiles = new Array();
                                nameFiles = o.Archivos.split(',');
                                console.log('namesFiles: ' + nameFiles);

                                for (let i = 0; i < nameFiles.length; i++) {
                                    console.log('nameFiles[i]: ' + nameFiles[i]);

                                    var name = o.SolicitudId + "-" + nameFiles[i];
                                    var path = "/Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name;

                                    card += "<div>";
                                    if (nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") || nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif")) {
                                        card += "<a data-gallery='manual2' href='" + path + "' target='_blank'>";
                                        card += "<img src='" + path + "' style='width:200px;height:200px;text-align:center; border-radius: 5px;' >";
                                        card += "</a>";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        card += "<a href='./../../Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name + "' target='_blank'>" + name + "</a>";
                                    }
                                    card += "</div>";

                                    //card += "<a href='./../../Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name + "' target='_blank'>" + name + "</a>";
                                }
                            }
                            + "</div>";
                        }

                        card += "</div>";
                    }

                });
```

En el primer `if`, me muestra los mensajes de la parte del cliente, que sería `o.Contacto`, sí `o.Contacto` es diferente de `null` me muestra los mensajes del lado izquierdo y si es `null`, me muestro los mensajes del lado derecho.

Así como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde "Alexander Pierce" sería como el cliente y Sarah, sería el soporte del chat. Y el problema es que no me lo muestra así.

Si no es que así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En dos lugares tenes el mismo error. Estas haciendo `+ "</div>";` en lugar de `card += "</div>";`. Imagino que al no estar cerrando correctamente los tags la visualización resulta erronea.

Comment: fua, sí eso era... no me di cuenta, gracias